# How can I split a configuration block into multiple files?

Tags: ruby

Given the following example, how can I split the Botsy configuration block into multiple files?

This is a Campfire bot, and it's getting more and more complex; I want to organise the code better. I would like, for example, to split its config into files or modules such as "chat", "commands", etc. while only instantiating a single Bot.

```
Botsy::Bot.new(campfire["subdomain"], campfire["token"], campfire["room"]) do

  hear(/.*(going down|happening|news|up to)\?/i) do |data|
    say "I caught my first tube today."
  end

  #...lots more configuration

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you assign the new instance of Botsy::Bot to a constant or instance variable of some class, you can then use that and define more configuration later.

```
MYBOT = Botsy::Bot.new(campfire["subdomain"], campfire["token"], campfire["room"]) do

  hear(/.*(going down|happening|news|up to)\?/i) do |data|
    say "I caught my first tube today."
  end

  # ...
end

####
# Different file which is evaluated before the bot is set listening

MYBOT.hear(/hello world/) do |data|
  say "Hello, humans!"
end
```

Check out the source.  https://github.com/seejohnrun/botsy/blob/master/lib/botsy.rb

Comment: Thanks Dan. Botsy starts listening during initialize, I don't know how to evaluate a different file of commands before it starts listening, yet during the initialize. Puzzled! E.g. in your example, where and how would you evaluate the different file?

Comment: Aha, I have achieved it with 'instance_eval (File.read('./commands.rb'))' inside the config block.

Comment: Yeah, I am not familiar with the project (not sure if it really needs to be set before it listens), but it looks like you are on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

solved with:

```
Botsy::Bot.new(campfire["subdomain"], campfire["token"], campfire["room"]) do

  instance_eval File.read('./banter.rb')
  instance_eval File.read('./commands.rb')

end
```

where banter.rb contains something like:

```
hear(/.*(going down|happening|news|up to)\?/i) do |data|
  say "I caught my first tube today."
end
```